# In what sense is $\Pi x: A.B$ the same as $B[x := a_1] \times B[x := a_2]$ when A is a finite type with two elements $a_1$ and $a_2$

Tags: type-theory

This is in the context of the Type Theory system $\lambda P$ as presented in Chapter 5 of "Type Theory and Formal Proof: An Introduction" by Rob Nederpelt and Herman Guevers.

Since I am unsure of how standard $\lambda P$ is in the literature, I'll just mention that it is a system of type theory in which in addition to terms depending on terms, there are types depending on terms.

The full paragraph in the text is:

"Martin-Löf (1980) calls a $\Pi$-type the Cartesian product of a family of types. If one considers A to be a finite type, say with two elements $a_1$ and $a_2$, then $\Pi x: A. B$ is indeed the same as $B[x := a_1] \times B[x := a_2]$, the Cartesian product and as a generalization of the function space (if $x \notin \operatorname{FV}(B)$, then $\Pi x : a. B$ is just $A \to B$)"

This equivalence to Cartesian products is not further explained. I have tried to make sense of it by considering concrete examples but have fallen short.

One possible reason I am failing to understand this is that I do not understand how (or even know if it is possible that) a type in beta-normal form can contain a free term, whereas in systems $\lambda \to$, $\lambda 2$, $\lambda \underline{\omega}$, I had no issue finding examples of the situations equivalent to this (for terms dependent on terms, terms dependent on types, and types dependent on terms).

Comment: I don't know this type theory, but it looks like the standard isomorphism given by $\lambda f.(f\,a_1,f\,a_2) : (\Pi(x:A)B)\to B\times B$ and $\lambda(b_1,b_2).(a_1\mapsto b_1, a_2\mapsto b_2):B\times B \to \Pi(x:A)B$. Does that make sense in your setting?

Comment: @JackozeeHakkiuz Thanks for the comment. After about 5 minutes staring at that expression, I'm unable to parse it, so I think not. Maybe it is only a different notation and I should have understood, but I cannot see how. EDIT: I see you have capitalized the pi lol, that might've helped let me see.

Comment: @JackozeeHakkiuz It looks familiar enough that perhaps with a bit of notational translating I could understand it. I am confused by the fact that $f$ does not appear to be typed and am confused as to what $(f_{a1},f_{a2})$ represents within the body (?) of an abstraction(?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Welcome to MSE ^_^

I am not familiar with Nederpelt and Guevers' book, so I'm sorry if the language I use is not the language used in your reference. I will try to explain everything as I go, in case some notation I use is unfamiliar.

A dependent type $\prod_{a:A} B(a)$ is indeed a generalization of the cartesian product. The easiest example is when $A = \text{Bool}$ with two values $T$ and $F$.
Let's consider two types $B(T)$ and $B(F)$.
Then the type $\prod_\text{x:Bool}B(x)$ is inhabited by functions $f$ so that
$f(T) : B(T)$ and $f(F) : B(F)$. One can view such a function $f$ as *selecting an element* $f(x)$ of each $B(x)$.

Now, there is a natural (and eventually obvious) identification between these functions $f$ and a pair $(b_1,b_2) : B(T) \times B(F)$. Our function $f$ is totally specified by $f(T)$ and $f(F)$, so we can package those values up as a tuple. Dually, a tuple whose first element is in $B(T)$ and second is in $B(F)$ gives us the data of a function!

$$\left ( f : \prod_{x:\text{Bool}}B(x) \right ) \mapsto \bigg ( (f(T),f(F)) : B(T) \times B(F) \bigg )$$

$$\bigg ( (x,y) : B(T) \times B(F) \bigg ) \mapsto 
\left ( \lambda b . \text{if } b = T \text{ then } x \text{ else } y : \prod_{b:\text{Bool}} B(b) \right )$$

Following [Homotopy Type Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homotopy_type_theory), my preferred interpretation of this phenomenon is geometric.

Consider the following picture:

[image: fibres over Bool]

Here we have two types, which you should view as "floating above" the type of booleans below. Then elements of $\prod_{x : \text{Bool}}B(x)$ are exactly functions out of $\text{Bool}$ so that the value of $f(x)$ lies above $x$. In this way, as I said earlier, an element of the $\prod$-type *selects* one element out of each of the pieces. Hopefully this picture, and the idea of a $\prod$-type as a "selector" helps explain in a different way why $\prod_{x : \text{Bool}}B(x)$ is the same as $B(T) \times B(F)$. They both represent ways to choose one element from $B(T)$ and one from $B(F)$!

At this point I will suggest a small exercise. Let $\mathbf{3}$ denote a type with three values: $x$, $y$, and $z$. Now fix 3 new types, say $B(x)$, $B(y)$, and $B(z)$. Do you see why $\prod_{t:\mathbf{3}}B(t)$ is the same as $B(x) \times B(y) \times B(z)$? Make sure you understand why that is before moving on!

---

Let's move on to a trickier example now. Let $\mathbb{Z}$ denote the type of integers. Now pick a type $B(n)$ for each integer $n : \mathbb{Z}$. What does an element of $\prod_{n : \mathbb{Z}} B(n)$ look like?

You should train yourself, pavlovianly, to pull the following picture to mind:

[image: fibres over Z]

Again, we have a function out of $\mathbb{Z}$, which *selects* one element of each $B(n)$. The analogy to cartesian products is slightly less clear now. But this is where we start generalizing. If $f : \prod_{n : \mathbb{Z}}B(n)$, then what type might you give the following "term"?

$$(\ldots, f(-2), f(-1), f(0), f(1), f(2), \ldots)$$

This "term" is a tuple with $\mathbb{Z}$ many entries, and the $n$th entry comes from $B(n)$. If you had to assign a type to something like this, you might say it has type $\ldots \times B(-2) \times B(-1) \times B(0) \times B(1) \times B(2) \times \ldots$.

It is in *this* sense, that $\prod_{n : \mathbb{Z}} B(n)$ is a "cartesian product". The functions inhabiting this $\prod$-type have exactly the same information as an infinite tuple indexed by $\mathbb{Z}$! But because functions are finitary, they can be expressed in type theory, while formalizing an "infinite tuple" is almost impossible!

---

It's time for the last example. What about $\prod_{a:A}B(a)$? Again, the response should be pavlovian:

[image: fibres over an arbitrary type A]

Here we write $B$ to mean the collection of all the $B(a)$s viewed as one type. (As a remark, $B$ is exactly the sum-type $\Sigma_{a:A}B(a)$!) Then functions $f : A \to B$ so that $f(a) : B(a)$ are exactly elements of $\prod_{a:A}B(a)$. Again, we are *selecting* one element from each $B(a)$. So we can think of this function as a "tuple indexed by $A$", and so we identify it with a "cartesian product" of one type for each element of $A$! This is exactly where the $\prod$ notation comes from - we are *producting* together the family of types $B(a)$. This is extra useful, as $A$ might not be ordered neatly in the way that $\mathbb{Z}$ is. So it is less clear how one might write a tuple with one entry for each value of $A$! In this case, if we want to show that we're thinking of $f$ as a tuple rather than a function, we might write something like $(f_a)_{a:A} : \prod_{a:A} B(a)$.

---

This was a long ride, but I hope it made some sense! I know $\prod$-types confused me when I was first getting started, but after I worked these "bubble" pictures into my subconscious (the bubbles are called "[fibres](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiber_(mathematics))", by the way), their properties became really obvious! The important thing to keep in mind is that, as far as type theory is concerned, a $\prod$-type is just a type full of functions. Their normal forms look just like functions. You can evaluate them, and you create them via $\lambda$-abstraction. *But* as humans, we have the power to think of them as more than functions. The confusion you're feeling with regards to $f$ not having a clean codomain is common. It is solved (as I alluded to earlier) by the introduction of $\sum$-types, but even *without* $\sum$-types, $\prod$-types have introduction and elimination rules just like anything else - there's nothing scary lying under the hood.

To get some practice, can you see (intuitively!) why the following facts must be true? Can you then *formalize* this intuition with an equivalence of types?

- $\prod_{x:\mathbf{1}}A(x) \cong A(x)$ when $\mathbf{1}$ is the type with only one inhabitat
- $\prod_{x:X}B(x) \cong \mathbf{0}$ whenever one of the $B(x)$s are $\mathbf{0}$ (the type with *no* inhabitants)

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: Apparently MSE discourages "thanks" comments, but since I'm human and I cannot even publicly up-vote yet (need 15 reputation), I want to say thanks! After about two hours of trying to make sense of this, it clicked. Thank you kindly.

Comment: Happy to help ^_^